# How to assign different threads to different AsyncTasks, so they do not wait for each other in a line

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

In my application, when the user clicks "Save product"a long chain of network operations is started in an AsyncTask.

In the meanwhile if the user opens up the Navigation Drawer and clicks a menu item, another AsyncTask is used so that loading the data doesnt block the UI and this way I prevent the navigation drawer from being closed in a snappy manner, instead of smoothly.

The problem is that the second AsyncTask apparently waits for the first one to finish, and THEN it opens the newly selected menu item. For a few seconds after the user has clicked on it, the navigation drawer remains open.

When I switch loading data for the menu item to be opened from an AsyncTask to main thread, the navigation drawer closes instantly (but laggy/snappy, dunno whats the better word)

So how do I assign this AsyncTask (the one that closes the navigation drawer) to another thread so it doesnt wait for the first one to finish off before it starts? Or is there a way to instruct both to run parallely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Android documentation:

> **Order of execution**
>
> When first introduced, AsyncTasks were executed serially on a single background thread. Starting with DONUT, this was changed to a pool of threads allowing multiple tasks to operate in parallel. Starting with HONEYCOMB, tasks are executed on a single thread to avoid common application errors caused by parallel execution.
>
> If you truly want parallel execution, you can invoke executeOnExecutor(java.util.concurrent.Executor, Object[]) with THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

In general if you want to do a lot of threading or long running operations AyncTasks are not recommended. You are better off using a [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) or [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html)

Comment: I am using executeOnExecutor now, and both asynctasks can get along, but now another problem arises - next asynctasks in the user flow are affected by the long running one. I dont want to have ALL the asynctasks use executeOnExecutor because a havoc may arise... can I defer only this particular task to a completely separate thread, so no other asynctasks have to wait for it to finish?

Comment: Use a ThreadPoolExecutor and execute your task on that rather than using an AsyncTask at all. It says in AsyncTask that it is only recommended for short lived tasks.

Answer (score 1):

As Tim B suggested, THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR will do the trick for you:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
    asyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, params);
} else {
    asyncTask.execute(params);
}
```

Comment: I only support Android 4.0 onwards so the if will not be necessary. Where do I put this code - in the first, or the second, or both asynctasks?

Comment: I think you can use it with both asynctasks.

Comment: I will get back to you as soon as I test how this works!

Comment: I am using executeOnExecutor now, and both asynctasks can get along, but now another problem arises - next asynctasks in the user flow are affected by the long running one. I dont want to have ALL the asynctasks use executeOnExecutor because a havoc may arise... can I defer only this particular task to a completely separate thread, so no other asynctasks have to wait for it to finish?

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation is to use an AsyncTaskLoader instead of an AsyncTask.

AsyncTasks have a couple of issues:

- An AsyncTask runs regardless of the Activity/Fragment life cycle. Pausing an Activity doesn’t pause the AsyncTask so navigating between Activities might leave a "trail" of running AsyncTasks (bad for performance, battery and responsiveness).
- Configuration changes (especially orientation changes) are problematic since the AsyncTask has no way to update the ui after such a change (the Activity has likely been destroyed) and the newly created Activity has no way to "find" an already started and maybe still running AsyncTask.
- AsyncTasks have IMO a major design flaw because they do background processing and also update the ui (in onPostExecute). The ui is part of an Activity/Fragment and its life cycle and only those should have access to ui elements and be able to modify/update them. By delegating ui updates to a component (the AsyncTask) that is independent of the ui/Activity life cycle, one will inevitably run into problems.

All these issues are obsolete with Loaders (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncTaskLoader.html). The main difference IMO is that they do background processing only and report back once they finished to let the Activity/Fragment do the ui part. They also handle configuration changes gracefully, meaning the ui part (Activity/Fragment) and the Loader can "reconnect" after such a change, no need to start a new Loader after a screen rotation. Some implementations (namely CursorLoader) are also able to monitor changes to the underlying data and re-query automatically (not so relevant for this question though).

Last but not least (to answer the original question), starting a new AsyncTaskLoader never blocks the running thread:

```
LoaderManager loaderMgr = getLoaderManager();
loaderMgr.initLoader(LOADER_ID, null, this);
```

initLoader is a non-blocking call and will always return immediately.

Here's a most basic example of an AsyncTaskLoader:

```
LoaderManager loaderMgr = getLoaderManager();
loaderMgr.initLoader(LOADER_ID, null, new LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Result>() {
    @Override
    public Loader<Result> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        return new BackgroundTask(maybe some parameters...);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Result> loader) {}

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Result> loader, Result data) {
        // here we update the ui
    }
}

class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTaskLoader<Result> {
    public BackgroundTask(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public Result loadInBackground() {
        // do the background processing
    }
}
```

While this looks like a lot of boilerplate code, it's really quite simple and shows nicely the separation of background processing (in the BackgroundTask) and the ui part.

I'm aware that the OP might just look for a quick fix and the other answers provide exactly that. The AsyncTaskLoader on the other hand might be the way to go in the long term.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncTaskLoader.html